# Is there a less ugly way to do input in D than scanf()?

Tags: input, d, scanf

Currently the only way I know how to do input in D is with the scanf() function. But god damn it's ugly. You would think that since it's an upgrade from C that they would have fixed that.

I'm looking for a way to do it with a single argument. Currently you have to do:

```
int foo = 0;
scanf("%i", &foo);
writeln("%i", foo);
```

But it would look a lot cleaner with a single argument. Something like:

```
int foo = 0;
scanf(foo);
writeln(foo);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `readf("%d", &foo);` allows working with `std.stdio.File` rather than C `FILE*`
- `foo = readln().strip().to!int();`
- For reading entire files with lines formatted in the same way:
  `int[] numbers = slurp!int("filename", "%d");`

Answer (score 6):

There's a really cool user-input module here:

https://github.com/Abscissa/scriptlike/blob/master/src/scriptlike/interact.d

Example code:

```
if (userInput!bool("Do you want to continue?"))
{
    auto outputFolder = pathLocation("Where you do want to place the output?");
    auto color = menu!string("What color would you like to use?", ["Blue", "Green"]);
}

auto num = require!(int, "a > 0 && a <= 10")("Enter a number from 1 to 10");
```

Comment: Is it worth splitting this into its own repo?

Comment: I'm kind of a newb when it comes to the C like languages. Would you mind telling me how to install this?

Comment: You can either copy the entire file and place it in a subfolder of your project, matching its module name, or look for the lib on www.code.dlang.org and import it when using dub. Unfortunately, I couldn't find it in the registry, so ho with option #1.

Comment: @he_the_great: It's not my repo, but I would love to see this in Phobos.

Comment: @AndrejM. I don't know, utilities for building interactive console apps don't really belong in a standard library imho.

Comment: @AndrejM. I know, it currently is hidden in a branch and just want to know if that causes enough problems that I should make a repo for it. It was reject for Phobos awhile back (some things are English specific anyway).

Answer (score 4):

The above answers are great. I just want to add my 2 cents.

I often have the following simple function lying around:

```
T read(T)() 
{
   T obj;
   readf(" %s", &obj);
   return obj;
}
```

It's generic and pretty handy - it swallows any white space and reads any type you ask. You can use it like this:

```
auto number = read!int;
auto floating_number = read!float;
// etc.
```

Comment: I was really looking for a built in function or maybe a library. But so far this is the only answer that works. I'll wait a little while before selecting this as the accepted answer.

Comment: When it comes to strings, there's a wider area to define the semantics. Like, what do you actually want to get - a word? a line? the whole input? how about punctuation? So, there can't be general solution. This implementation works by swallowing white space and returning the rest of the input as a single string. You can use readln() to read a line. And you can use split() to get separate words.